# Как открыть фотографию формата BlobReader в python 3.6

Tags: firebird, python-3.6, byte

Здравствуйте. Как открыть фотографию формата `BlobReader` в `python 3.6`. Пытался
работать с ней через `Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo))` но выдаёт ошибку `a bytes-like object is required, not 'BlobReader'` либо `a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'`. `BlobReader` приходит в таком виде  - `<fdb.fbcore.BlobReader object at 0x0000015504ADE4A8>`.

Вот код если нужно:

```
import io
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def set_pgoto(self, photo):
     return Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo))  # PILL открыл фотку

br = <fdb.fbcore.BlobReader object at 0x0000015504ADE4A8>
photo = self.set_pgoto(br)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
self.photo.configure(image=img)
self.photo.image = img
```

Comment: Попробуйте `data = br.read()` и data в `set_pgoto` передать. https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/reference.html#fdb.BlobReader.read

Comment: @gil9red К сожалению, такое не работает) выдаёт адскую ошибку) `"Cursor.read_output_blob/isc_open_blob2:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Cursor.read_output_blob/isc_open_blob2:\n- SQLCODE: -904\n- invalid database handle (no active connection)', -904, 335544324)`